# Is request reached to server ? IOException while writing request on outputstream

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, networking, ioexception

i am trying to understand HttpURLConnection behavior, so far i have got to know all about connect time out, read time out, etc.

Now lets say i have successfully opened url connection, also got outputStream to write data.

Now i am trying to write data on server, out.write(requestByte);
So if i will get IOException at line **out.write(requestByte)** then what it signifies?

Is request reached to server or not?

```
        try {
                out.write(requestByte);
                logger.info("API Request sent at : " + sdf.format(new Date()));
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.info("Exception while writing request to output stream");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here is the full code....

```
try {
            bridgeUrl = new URL(url);

            if (connectionTime == null) {
                connectionTime = StartupCache.getInstance().getConfigByKey(getUniqueKey(ConfigurationConstant.CONNECTION_TIME_OUT));
                //connectionTime = TransactionPersistence.getInstance().getConfigByConfigKey(ConfigurationConstant.CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
                if (connectionTime != null && connectionTime.getConfigValue().trim().length() > 0) {
                    connectionTimeOutInMilliSec = Integer.valueOf(connectionTime.getConfigValue());
                }
            }

            if (bridgeUrl.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https")) {
                ignoreSslCertificateAuthentication();
                httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) bridgeUrl.openConnection();
            } else {
                httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) bridgeUrl.openConnection();
            }
            logger.info("\ Request : "+request+"\n");

            request="JsonData="+request;
            byte[] requestByte = request.getBytes();
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(requestByte.length));
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);
            httpConn.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeOutInMilliSec);
            httpConn.setReadTimeout(connectionTimeOutInMilliSec);
            out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
            try {
                out.write(requestByte);
                logger.info("API Request sent at : " + sdf.format(new Date()));
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.info("Exception while writing request to output stream");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(MalformedURLException exMurl){
            logger.info(exMurl.getMessage());
            throw new ApiRequestPostingException("Exception occured while posting request to server");
        }
        catch(SocketTimeoutException stout){
            logger.error(stout.getMessage());
            stout.printStackTrace();

            if (httpConn != null) {
                logger.info("Closing httpConn in exception blcok of output stream connection....");
                httpConn.disconnect();
            }

            throw new ApiRequestPostingException("Exception occured while posting request to server");
        }catch(IOException ioex){
            logger.error(ioex.getMessage());
            ioex.printStackTrace();

            if (httpConn != null) {
                logger.info("Closing httpConn in exception blcok of output stream connection....");
                httpConn.disconnect();
            }

            throw new ApiRequestPostingException("Exception occured while posting request to server");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> if i will get IOException at line out.write(requestByte) then what it signifies?
>
> Is request reached to server or not?

Not. It depends a bit on which `IOException` you caught, but most of them indicate that the connection was fatally broken. If the data was sent, or at least buffered to the local socket send buffer, you wouldn't have got an `IOException`.

And please note that you must do some input. At a minimum you must call `getResponseCode()`, and log the result.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that *not* getting IOException doesn't mean that the data *did* reach the server.

Comment: @EJP  Thanks for the clarification.